# Find cartesian equation given vectors that span the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working with this problem where I need to find the equation given the following vectors that span that space:

[image]

I'm used to converting equations into parametric ones, and to then find a vector basis that span that space. However, I don't really know what method to use in order to get the equation from this.

Thanks!

Comment: What's $\underline e$?

Comment: The standard basis

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equation will depend on 3 parameters, $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$:
$$\mathbb V=a\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-a+b\\a+b+c\\a+c\\-b+c\end{pmatrix}$$